# Pandas .loc[] is extremly slow compared to dict

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a DataFrame that has around 10 columns and 100K rows. I want to get every row in a loop using `.loc[]` on index. However `.loc[]` is being extremely slow compared to Python's dict.

Here is the code to reproduce:

```py
import pandas as pd
import random
import time

data = {}

for i in range(100000):
    data[i] = {
        'id': i,
        'a': random.randint(1, 40000),
        'b': random.randint(1, 40000),
        'c': random.randint(1, 40000),
        'd': random.randint(1, 40000),
        'e': random.randint(1, 40000),
        'f': random.randint(1, 40000),
    }

df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(
    data=data,
    orient="index",
    dtype=int,
)
df.set_index('id', inplace=True)

dict_objs = df.to_dict('index')

start_time_dataframe = time.time()
for i in range(100000):
    obj = df.loc[i]
end_time_dataframe = time.time() - start_time_dataframe

start_time_dict = time.time()
for i in range(100000):
    obj = dict_objs[i]

end_time_dict = time.time() - start_time_dict

print(f"Time needed for DataFrame: {end_time_dataframe}")  # 12.08s
print(f"Time needed for Dict: {end_time_dict}")  # 0.01s
```

Why is DataFrame's `.loc[]` running so slow?

Comment: i'm not sure I understand this test; `loc` cant be as performant as dict if you are running through a loop. the idea behind `loc` or pandas/numpy is that you can select large blocks by not running the loop within vanilla python, and get significant speeds. Accessing data in Pandas via a loop is not efficient

Comment: @sammywemmy I have a second data source which is not ordered and I need to access the values from the dataframe based on the second data source's value

Comment: `df.loc[i]` does something very different internally than `dict_obj[i]`, `DataFrame` has to keep track of lot of things like `index`, `columns`, `dtypes`, `values`, index `MultiIndex`s, you can even index using boolean array. All these will have a significant overhead compared to simple `dict.__getitem__`. It's like comparing oranges to apples.

Comment: But it's strange. I would have assumed that when I'm getting items based on index it will be way faster. It is even better (faster) for me to convert that DataFrame to dict and then perform the loop...

Comment: Like @sammywemmy mentioned If you just loop through the data, then pandas is the wrong library. You are better off using `dict`.

Comment: "I have a second data source which is not ordered and I need to access the values from the dataframe based on the second data source's value" -- that sounds like a job for `merge` or `join`. Like others have said, if you use loops with pandas, there's a good chance that you are doing it wrong